# Need Salesforce API detail to create lead in salesforce CRM from my website(PHP)

Tags: php, api, salesforce, cakephp-2.0, apex-code

Friends,

I have a contact us/Inquiry form in my website. I want to generate a lead in Sales force CRM on submission of this form.

***What I have tried ?***

I have checked in `salesforce` doc and Google it I found something

http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/REST_API

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/index.htm

But I did not get clear documentation for integrating it with PHP.

If any one integrated this please help me out !!

Thanks !!

Note: I have worked with force.com and salesfoce.com so i can understand foce.com API easily but i am not getting any link for API.

Comment: Neeraj bhai, how did you implement it? I need to do the same. Can you help me?

Comment: If you only need to do lead generation, you don't need to use the API if you don't want. See code here: https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Simple_Web2Lead_Implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’ve to downloaded the toolkit to connect with `salesforce` from your `PHP` and you will get below files in toolkit:

```
1- SforceBaseClient.php

2- SforceHeaderOptions.php

3- SforcePartnerClient.php

4- partner.wsdl.xml
```

You get an example file also, which will show you a good example to connect and post data on `salesforce`.

For more help you can read this blog:

http://ahmeddirie.com/technology/web-development/salesforce-soap-api-and-php/

Comment: @SiddeshBhalke: dude accept the answer if found it useful.